# Duplicate record after join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables EmployeeEntryTime and EmployeeExitTime my concern is everytime i join them it returns a duplicate record instead of only 5 records total showing EntryTime and ExitTime and other data.

EmployeeEntryTime table data ff.

| EmpID | EntryTime | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8703 | 2021-03-14 00:00:54.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-14 17:16:08.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-18 05:03:00.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-19 05:13:01.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-20 17:12:38.000 | random event |

EmployeeExitTime table data ff.

| EmpID | ExitTime | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8703 | 2021-03-14 06:07:13.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-15 06:11:30.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-18 18:06:31.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-19 18:06:08.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-20 19:59:12.000 | random event |

The output i need is the ff.

| EmpID | EntryTime | Event | ExitTime | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8703 | 2021-03-14 00:00:54.000 | random event | 2021-03-14 06:07:13.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-14 17:16:08.000 | random event | 2021-03-15 06:11:30.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-18 05:03:00.000 | random event | 2021-03-18 18:06:31.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-19 05:13:01.000 | random event | 2021-03-19 18:06:08.000 | random event |
| 8703 | 2021-03-20 17:12:38.000 | random event | 2021-03-20 19:59:12.000 | random event |

My query is.

```
select
    empEntryTime.EmployeeNumber,
    empEntryTime.EntryTime,
    empEntryTime.EntryPoint,
    empExitTime.ExitTime,
    empExitTime.ExitPoint
from
    EmployeeEntryTime empEntryTime
inner join EmployeeExitTime empExitTime 
    on empEntryTime.EmployeeNumber = empExitTime.EmployeeNumber    
order by
    empEntryTime.EntryTime,
    empExitTime.ExitTime
```

The output i get is below image note: i remove the other columns to avoid getting sued for data privacy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some additional correlation, an `apply` makes this straight forward

```
select et.EmpId, et.EntryTime, et.Event, xt.ExitTime, xt.Event
from EmployeeEntryTime et
cross apply (
    select top (1) ExitTime, Event
    from EmployeeExitTime xt
    where xt.EmpId=et.EmpId and xt.ExitTime>et.EntryTime
    order by ExitTime
)xt
order by et.EntryTime
```

Comment: ah cross apply i've been trying cte but i guess this does the job. i need to understand how cross apply works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if exit time is always in the same day , then you need to add another criteria to your current query:

```
select
    empEntryTime.EmployeeNumber,
    empEntryTime.EntryTime,
    empEntryTime.EntryPoint,
    empExitTime.ExitTime,
    empExitTime.ExitPoint
from
    EmployeeEntryTime empEntryTime
inner join EmployeeExitTime empExitTime 
    on empEntryTime.EmployeeNumber = empExitTime.EmployeeNumber
    and cast(empEntryTime.EntryTime as date) = cast(empExitTime.ExitTime as date)
order by
    empEntryTime.EntryTime,
    empExitTime.ExitTime
```

Comment: But its not the case because on other days they work night shift.

Comment: I have a different query before this to get the entryTime and exitTime i just stored them in different table for other conditions i have to check once i get my desired output.

Comment: hmmm ,I think if you give us the original problem , you can find an simpler solutions ,

Comment: This is my original problem atm. I understand what you meant but i don't want to post the whole idea that im trying to achieved here unless it took me 2 to 3 weeks after breaking my head and still nothing comes out as a result. I believed i have to try at least for a week or so before using the magic word stackoverflow lol. thanks for the solution though its not the answer to my question.

Comment: ok then, if not @stu answer should work for you then